# Qual o erro nesse while PHP?

Tags: php, loop, while

O código abaixo seleciona todos os resultados cuja thumbnail do vídeo ainda não foi criada e caso não tenha sido, ele cria uma nova, porém estou obtendo um erro que não consigo achar a solução:

```
    $video = BD::conn()->prepare("SELECT * FROM episodios WHERE thumb = '0' OR thumb = ''");
    $video->execute();
    $c = $video->rowCount();
    if($c >= 1){
        while($dados = $video->fetch()){
            $id = $dados["id"];
            $serie = $dados["id_serie"];
            $temporada = $dados["temporada"];
            $episodio = $dados["episodio"];

            if (!is_dir("D:/thumbs/".$serie)) {
                mkdir("D:/thumbs/".$serie, 0777);
            }
            if (!is_dir("D:/thumbs/".$serie."/".$temporada)) {
                mkdir("D:/thumbs/".$serie."/".$temporada, 0777);
            }

            /*o erro está sendo gerado aqui*/   
            if(is_dir("D:/videos/".$anime."/original/")) {
                $video = "D:/videos/".$serie."/original/".$temporada."/".$episodio.".mp4";
            }else{
                $video = "D:/videos/".$anime."/dublado/".$temporada."/".$episodio.".mp4";
            }
            /*fim da parte com erro*/
        }
  }
```

Quando eu comento o bloco que supostamente está gerando o erro, o while percorre normalmente, mas quando adiciono a mesma eu obtenho esse erro:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on string in

Comment: a sua variavel `$video` é uma string e não um objeto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acontece que você está chamando a função `FETCH` no objeto `$video` mas no final do código tu está sobre escrevendo a variável que tinha um *OBJETO* com uma *STRING*, aí o erro.

Muda o final para:

```
if(is_dir("D:/videos/".$anime."/original/")) {
            $video1 = "D:/videos/".$serie."/original/".$temporada."/".$episodio.".mp4";
        }else{
            $video1 = "D:/videos/".$anime."/dublado/".$temporada."/".$episodio.".mp4";
        }
```

Vale lembrar que $video1 terá apenas o último valor do Loop, se tu deseja armazenar todos os valores é preciso usar um Array, por exemplo `$videos[$id]`

Comment: Não posso simplesmente "resetar" a variavel vídeo e recriar a mesma dentro do loop?

Comment: Creio que não faça sentido, pois você está dentro do objeto $video e processando o while, subscrever ele seria complicado retomar de onde parou, além da gambiarra.

Comment: Se tu fizer isso o Loop seria infinito rodando sempre a primeira iteração. Usa o Array $videos[$id] que deve te resolver. Fora do While escreve o seguinte: `print_r($videos);` que ele vai exibir pra ti o array que foi criado.

Comment: Eu não gostaria de armazenar os valores em um array pra usar fora do while, gostaria de executar tudo dentro do mesmo laço, incluindo a criação da thumb, não é possível fazer isso dentro do while?

Comment: Criar o que? Um HTML? Basta utilizar `echo "D:/videos/".$serie."/original/".$temporada."/".$episodio.".mp4";`

Comment: Eu só preciso passar para a variável $video o caminho onde se encontra o vídeo que deve ser usado pelo ffmpeg

Comment: Então salva dentro de uma variável chamada $videoFfmpeg e utiliza essa variável na função do ffmpeg que tem que ser chamada todas as vezes dentro do Loop.

Comment: Isso é o que estou tentando fazer na variável $video e estou tendo esse erro

Comment: Por causa do nome da Variável, não pode ser $video. Muda pra $video1;

Comment: Por que esse erro ocorre usando a variável com esse nome? É algum tipo de nome reservado pelo PHP?

Comment: Não, tu está usando a variavel $video duas vezes mesmo. Uma vez como *Objeto* do SQL extraindo o FETCH e no final do Loop tu usa a mesma variável $video para receber uma STRING, só que STRING não possui a função FETCH e daí o Erro.

Comment: Aah não havia percebido essa duplicata, pois antes eu estava fazendo esse processo em duas páginas diferentes, agora estou juntando ambas e não me toquei disso. Obrigado man

Comment: Disponha, um abraço!